# Regular Expressions Find pattern of word and number

Tags: c#, regex

I have array of strings like `{"abc 1","abc 2","abc 1 def 0","abc 23","abc 1 def 1 ghi 5" }`

first I need to find all the string that have only `"abc {number}"` like `"abc 1","abc 2","abc 23"`
next I want to find all the strings that have pattern of `"abc {number} def {number}"` like `"abc 1 def 0"`
How do I do it ?

Comment: See [here](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

Comment: Can you share what's your attempted solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use a regex like this:

```
^abc \d+$
```

The `^` and `$` are crucial because they mean the string doesn't just contain this pattern, but this pattern is the complete string - the start (`^`) and end (`$`)

Then use a regex like this

```
^abc \d+ def \d+$
```